# Getting javascript error while using smart-gwt

Tags: exception, gwt, smartgwt

I am using a combination of gwt and smart gwt. However i get the following eror whenever my page loads. please help me with fixing this. .
Please find the attached screenshot for the image of the popup error for the same

```
15:06:02.097 [ERROR] [detectfiles] 15:06:02.097:TMR5:WARN:Log:Error:
    'Object required'
    in /sc/modules/ISC_Core.js
    at line 1782
    [c]Element.getOffsetLeft(_1=&gt;[DIVElement]{ID:isc_0})
    [c]Element.getOffset(_1=&gt;&quot;left&quot;, _2=&gt;[ImgButton ID:isc_ImgButton_0], _3=&gt;undef, _4=&gt;false, _5=&gt;true)
    Canvas.getLeftOffset(_1=&gt;undef)
    Canvas.getPageLeft()
    Canvas.$414(null, undef)
    [c]Page.handleEvent(_1=&gt;null, _2=&gt;&quot;resize&quot;, _3=&gt;undef)
    [c]EventHandler.$78p(_1=&gt;&quot;landscape&quot;)
    [c]EventHandler.$hr(_1=&gt;undef)
    callback(undefined=&gt;undef)
        &quot;isc.EH.$hr()&quot;
    [c]Class.fireCallback(_1=&gt;&quot;isc.EH.$hr()&quot;, _2=&gt;undef, _3=&gt;Array[0], _4=&gt;Obj{length:2}, _5=&gt;true) on [Class Timer]
    [c]Timer.$in(_1=&gt;&quot;$ir28&quot;)
    anonymous()
        &quot;isc.Timer.$in('$ir28')&quot;

com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject$SGWT_WARN: 15:06:02.097:TMR5:WARN:Log:Error:
    'Object required'
    in /sc/modules/ISC_Core.js
    at line 1782
    [c]Element.getOffsetLeft(_1=&gt;[DIVElement]{ID:isc_0})
    [c]Element.getOffset(_1=&gt;&quot;left&quot;, _2=&gt;[ImgButton ID:isc_ImgButton_0], _3=&gt;undef, _4=&gt;false, _5=&gt;true)
    Canvas.getLeftOffset(_1=&gt;undef)
    Canvas.getPageLeft()
    Canvas.$414(null, undef)
    [c]Page.handleEvent(_1=&gt;null, _2=&gt;&quot;resize&quot;, _3=&gt;undef)
    [c]EventHandler.$78p(_1=&gt;&quot;landscape&quot;)
    [c]EventHandler.$hr(_1=&gt;undef)
    callback(undefined=&gt;undef)
        &quot;isc.EH.$hr()&quot;
    [c]Class.fireCallback(_1=&gt;&quot;isc.EH.$hr()&quot;, _2=&gt;undef, _3=&gt;Array[0], _4=&gt;Obj{length:2}, _5=&gt;true) on [Class Timer]
    [c]Timer.$in(_1=&gt;&quot;$ir28&quot;)
    anonymous()
        &quot;isc.Timer.$in('$ir28')&quot;
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:105)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

[image: Please find the attached screenshot for the image of the popup error for the same]

[image: smart-gwt error]

Here is a piece of code in which I am using TreeGrid inside a popup

```
private PopupPanel createConsoPopup() {
    final PopupPanel consoPopup = new PopupPanel();
    consoPopup.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    consoPopup.setAutoHideEnabled(true);
    VerticalPanel consoContent = new VerticalPanel();
    VEPConsoTree consoTree = new VEPConsoTree(lineTreeNode, vepConsoTree);
    vepConsoTree = consoTree.getCheckStationTree();
    vepConsoTree.addSelectionChangedHandler(new SelectionChangedHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionEvent event) {
            ((TextBox)flexTable.getWidget(selectedRowNum,         0)).setText(vepConsoTree.getSelectedRecord().getAttribute("vepAreaName")+"_"+vepConsoTree.getSelectedRecord().getAttribute("checkStationName"));
            consoPopup.hide();

        }
    });
    consoContent.add(consoTree);
    consoPopup.add(consoContent);
    return consoPopup;
}
```

Following is my VEPConsoTree class:

```
package com.renault.veppwrstats.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.smartgwt.client.types.TreeModelType;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.DrawEvent;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.DrawHandler;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tree.Tree;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tree.TreeGrid;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tree.TreeNode;

public class VEPConsoTree extends Composite {

private TreeNode[] lineTreeNode;
private TreeGrid vepConsoTree;
//private DFConstantsForLocale constants = GWT.create(DFConstantsForLocale.class);


/**
 * @param lineTreeNode
 * @param vepConsoTree
 */
public VEPConsoTree(TreeNode[] lineTreeNode, TreeGrid vepConsoTree) {
    super();
    this.lineTreeNode = lineTreeNode;
    this.vepConsoTree = vepConsoTree;
    //Grid grid = chckStatRestrictPanel();
    initWidget(vepConsoTree());
}

/**
 * This function creates checkStation Restriction Panel(tree) along with
 * Select/Unselect All button
 * 
 * @return
 */
private TreeGrid vepConsoTree() {
    return createTreeGrid();
}

/**
 * This function creates CheckStation Restriction Tree
 * 
 * @return {@link TreeGrid}
 */
private TreeGrid createTreeGrid() {
    final TreeGrid chckTreeGrid = new TreeGrid();
    chckTreeGrid.setHeight("269px");
    chckTreeGrid.setWidth("250px");
    chckTreeGrid.setData(createChkStationTree());
    //chckTreeGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
    //chckTreeGrid.setShowPartialSelection(false);
    //chckTreeGrid.setCascadeSelection(true);
    chckTreeGrid.setFolderIcon(null);
    chckTreeGrid.setNodeIcon(null);
    chckTreeGrid.setShowConnectors(true);
    chckTreeGrid.setShowHeader(false);
    //addSelectionChangeHndler(chckTreeGrid);
    chckTreeGrid.addDrawHandler(new DrawHandler() {
        public void onDraw(DrawEvent event) {
            chckTreeGrid.getTree().openAll();
        }
    });
    vepConsoTree = chckTreeGrid;
    return chckTreeGrid;
}

/**
 * This function creates a basic tree
 */
private Tree createChkStationTree() {
    Tree chckStationTree = new Tree();
    chckStationTree.setModelType(TreeModelType.PARENT);
    chckStationTree.setRootValue(1);
    chckStationTree.setIdField("id");
    chckStationTree.setOpenProperty("isOpen");
    chckStationTree.setData(lineTreeNode);
    chckStationTree.setParentIdField("parent");
    return chckStationTree;

}


/**
 * @return the vepConsoTree
 */
public final TreeGrid getCheckStationTree() {
    return vepConsoTree;
}

/**
 * @param vepConsoTree the vepConsoTree to set
 */
public final void setCheckStationTree(TreeGrid checkStationTree) {
    this.vepConsoTree = checkStationTree;
}

/**
 * @return the lineTreeNode
 */
public final TreeNode[] getLineTreeNode() {
    return lineTreeNode;
}

/**
 * @param lineTreeNode the lineTreeNode to set
 */
public final void setLineTreeNode(TreeNode[] lineTreeNode) {
    this.lineTreeNode = lineTreeNode;
}
```

}

Comment: Please give us GWT version, SmartGWT version, browser(s) version. Also, what code is triggering this output ?

Comment: I am using GWT-2.4 and Smart gwt- 2.4 version. I am not sure which code triggers this error, but it appears whenever the page loads. I have code like
VerticalPanel v = new VerticalPanel; v.add(new IButton) . Here I am embedding my smart gwt component into gwt component.

Comment: I recently found out that I have smart gwt TreeGrid embedded in gwt PopupPanel. when i comment that code this error never appears. This error occurs when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer : don't mix GWT and SmartGWT when you can**

> *Can I mix Smart GWT and GWT widgets?*
>
> Yes, with caveats.
>
> Smart GWT has interoperability support that allows a Smart GWT widget
>   to be added to a GWT container and allows a GWT widget to be added to
>   a Smart GWT container, and it's appropriate to use this for:
>
> incremental migration to Smart GWT, such as introducing singular,
>   sophisticated Smart GWT components like the Calendar or CubeGrid to an
>   existing GWT application
>
> using sophisticated third-party GWT widgets within Smart GWT, where
>   Smart GWT doesn't have corresponding built-in functionality
>
> However it does not make sense to freely intermix Smart GWT and GWT
>   (or other) components, that is, for example, you should not place GWT
>   widgets within a Smart GWT container that is in turn within a GWT
>   container. In general, don't intermix widgets unless the need for a
>   feature forces you to.
>
> The reason for this is that there are limits to the maximum degree
>   that two Ajax widget kits (including GWT) can interoperate - there are
>   no standards that allow interoperability in the areas of management of
>   tab order, zIndex management, pixel-perfect layout, section 508
>   accessibility and multi-level modality.
>
> Note that "bugs" reported when intermixing GWT and Smart GWT
>   inappropriately (that is, in contradiction to these guidelines) are
>   generally going to be marked WONTFIX, although we will revisit this in
>   the future if core GWT begins to support APIs that would allow better
>   interoperability.

### If you really need to mix GWT and SmartGWT here are the guidelines from Isomorphic

> Because Smart GWT's pixel-perfect layout and auto-sizing support goes
>   beyond the capabilities of simple CSS layout, components need to know
>   the actual pixel width they have been allocated by their parent
>   element; they cannot "flow into" an HTML element of unspecified size.
>
> The issue here is that GWT's containers do not provide an API similar
>   to Smart GWT's Canvas.getInnerWidth(), which in Smart GWT can be used
>   by child components to find out the available space to draw themselves
>   in, and hence recursively lay out out their own children. Nor do GWT
>   containers fire events when they are resized, or when the available
>   width changes for various reasons (e.g. scrollbar(s) introduced, or
>   CSS style changes add  borders and hence reduce space).
>
> A lot of parent<->child coordination and signaling is required to
>   really create an extensible pixel-perfect layout system. Smart
>   GWT/SmartClient has implemented all the necessary hooks to allow a
>   third-party widget to be embedded inside a Canvas and participate in a
>   precise layout, but GWT is not there yet.
>
> If you absolutely must place a Smart GWT interface inside a GWT
>   container and you want it to fill the container, the best approach is
>   to listen for a window-level resize event and run your own layout
>   calculations that ultimately call resizeTo() on your topmost Smart GWT
>   widget. All Smart GWT widgets nested under that topmost widget will
>   then handle layout normally.
>
> NOTE: Don't bother trying to find a way to insert width:100% into
>   Smart GWT's rendered HTML, this won't work.

source : http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there any kind of work-around for this? Because I really have some cases where-in I cannot avoid mixing up of gwt and smart gwt components.

Comment: edit your question, add minimal code example of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks. So now I will have to add my Smart gwt components into Smart gwt container?